# Remove characters after matching two conditions

Tags: python, python-re

I have the Python code below and I would like the output to be a string: "P-1888" discarding all numbers after the 2nd "-" and removing the leading 0's after the 1st "-".

So far all I have been able to do in the following code is to remove the trailing 0's:

```
import re

docket_no = "P-01888-000"

doc_no_rgx1 = re.compile(r"^([^\-]+)\-(0+(.+))\-0[\d]+$")
massaged_dn1 = doc_no_rgx1.sub(r"\1-\2", docket_no)

print(massaged_dn1)
```

Comment: Can you update your post with more samples of your "*docket_no*" strings? Or is it just one string only?

Comment: Why don't you just use `docket_no.split('-')` and continue from there?

Comment: It's a relatively easy fix in terms of the regex `doc_no_rgx1 = re.compile(r"^([^\-]+)\-0+(.+)\-0[\d]+$")` (just take one pair of brackets out that were making it think the second group should include the 0s). Using a regex is however probably overkill in this case as mkrieger1 mentions above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `split()` method to split the string on the "-" character and then use the `join()` method to join the first and second elements of the resulting list with a "-" character. Additionally, you can use the `lstrip()` method to remove the leading 0's after the 1st "-". Try this.

```
docket_no = "P-01888-000"
docket_no_list = docket_no.split("-")
docket_no_list[1] = docket_no_list[1].lstrip("0")
massaged_dn1 = "-".join(docket_no_list[:2])

print(massaged_dn1)
```

Comment: I posted the exact same thing before reading your answer.

Answer (score 0):

First way is to use capturing groups. You have already defined three of them using brackets. In your example the first capturing group will get "P", and the third capturing group will get numbers without leading zeros. You can get captured data by using `re.match`:

```
match = doc_no_rgx1.match(docket_no)
print(f'{match.group(1)}-{match.group(3)}')  # Outputs 'P-1888'
```

Second way is to not use regex for such a simple task. You could split your string and reassemble it like this:

```
parts = docket_no.split('-')
print(f'{parts[0]}-{parts[1].lstrip("0")}')
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a sledgehammer/nut situation but of you do want to use `re` then you could use:

```
doc_no_rgx1 = ''.join(re.findall('([A-Z]-)0+(\d+)-', docket_no)[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I'd use a regular expression for this purpose. Your usecase can be handled by standard string manipulation so using a regular expression would be overkill. Instead, consider doing this:

```
docket_nos = "P-01888-000".split('-')[:-1]
docket_nos[1] = docket_nos[1].lstrip('0')
docket_no = '-'.join(docket_nos)
print(docket_no) # P-1888
```

This might seem a little bit verbose but it does exactly what you're looking for. The first line splits `docket_no` by '-' characters, producing substrings `P`, `01888` and `000`; and then discards the last substring. The second line strips leading zeros from the second substring. And the third line joins all these back together using '-' characters, producing your desired result of P-1888.

Answer (score 0):

Functionally this is no different than other answers suggesting that you [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on `'-'` and [`lstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) the zero(s), but personally I find my code more readable when I use [multiple assignment](https://treyhunner.com/2018/03/tuple-unpacking-improves-python-code-readability/) to clarify intent vs. using indexes:

```
def convert_docket_no(docket_no):
    letter, number, *_ = docket_no.split('-')
    return f'{letter}-{number.lstrip("0")}'
```

`_` is used here for a "throwaway" variable, and the `*` makes it accept all elements of the split list past the first two.